# loop check internet activity

Tags: android

Situation: a stream by webview. Problem: create a loop to check internet activity. I've this code to check if there the internet activity but I need add a loop to check (ie) every 5seconds. What is the best way to do it?

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            urlc.connect();

            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                return new Boolean(true);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Post a `Runnable` every 5 seconds.

Comment: inside a looping thread or better yet, an async task. :)

Comment: why are you making http connection to check internet ? It can be detected locally without making any connection outside .

Comment: My app born with the goal listen radio from internet. I need a valid internet connection check and not only if mobile is connect to router (ie: some ap does not permit access over internet if there is not a login by browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont want to steal all internet connection of your user doing an access in an Url every 5 seconds.

I think that this code is better to check connection:

```
public boolean isNetworkOnline() {
        boolean status=false;
        try{
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(0);
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                status= true;
            }else {
                netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(1);
                if(netInfo!=null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    status= true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();  
            return false;
        }
        return status;

        }
```

And Add this in your Android Manifest:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

If you want to start download only if have connection, you can create a Refreshbutton.

A cool way of doing this is with [PulltoRefresh library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh).

Comment: +1 for being considerate of those of us without unlimited data plans.

Comment: This code cannot guarantee that there's an active internet connection but only if mobile is connected to router or 3g.

Comment: Just think about, if the user connect every 5 second in an Url, he will uninstall your app few minutes later, not everyone have unlimited data plans and even so, its not too fast to handle a connection check, your app and other stuff requesting bandwidth in the same time for a long time and if you not satisfy battery consumption.